# How do I name an interface when the base word starts with an I?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, interface

I want to create an interface for "Items". Typicaly I would name an interface by adding and "I" prefix to a base word. But in this case my base word already starts with an I. Here are a couple ideas I've had

- **IItem**: Two I's
- **Iitem** : Vary the case
- **ItemInterface**: Skip the I prefix and write out Interface

What looks the best? Has anyone else run into this problem. If so what did you do?

Comment: Haha, this has always bothered me as well. Glad to know I'm not the only one ;)

Comment: @Dan Tao: Of course it bothers you. You're an engineer. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Although hard to read, `IItem` would be in line with some existing "`II`" interfaces:

- [IItem in Windows Mobile 6.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446208.aspx)
- [IImplicitResourceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.iimplicitresourceprovider.aspx)
- [IISAPIRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iisapiruntime.aspx)

Comment: I was struggling to find examples that fast, but didn't succeed ... :-)

Comment: what you do if you have interface like this. 
IPhone
and you want to derive it AndroidPhone, windowsPhone and iPhone ?
because interface name IIPhone Does not make sense here.

Answer (score 12):

Simply `IItem`. There is no need for an exception.

Interfaces start with two upper case letters (I[A-Z]), which identify them as an interface. So `Item` is not an interface, but `IItem` is.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 2016/08/12:** I originally provided this answer as an alternative perspective on naming conventions. My day-to-day C# now uses `I`-prefixing to keep things idiomatic and to reduce cognitive burden through consistency. I think consistency is more important than the issues I raise below. In short, stick with the conventions of the code base you're working in.

---

Just `Item`. Not because the interface starts with an `I`, but rather because prefixing classes with identifying letters is not necessary.  Decorating interfaces with `I` is as ugly as slapping `C` before your concrete class names (a la MFC).  Prefixing types with anything is as bad as using Hungarian notation.

You could argue that it actually gives you semantic value, but I'm not convinced.  I have a modern IDE and I don't need my type names to be any more complex.

Comment: So postfixing with the full name is better than a one letter prefix?

Comment: @Esteban Araya: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  If you mean using dynamic languages, well, that's a whole different flamewar :)

Comment: Sorry, -1 from me, the convention within the .net framework is for interfaces to be prefixed with "I". Not doing that creates code that's not as understandable by anyone who's not you who needs to maintain your codebase in the future. Like it or loathe it, consistency is king =)

Comment: @Rob: fair enough.  The post was made somewhat in jest (I stick with consistency at work, but I drop the prefix for personal projects).  I guess I'm mostly sad that the BCL decided to go with this convention.

Comment: @Rob: also, I've realized over time that your argument about consistency is the same reason why writing in C/C++ can be painful.  Mixing the STL, Win32, and local coding conventions changing over time is the nadir of consistency.

Comment: @Esteban is saying that you appear to have swapped a prefix `I` for a suffix `Interface`, and are regarding that as better.

Comment: @AakashM: Ah sorry, I copy-pasted the type from the question (and apparently read way too fast).  Yes, appending `Interface` is even worse.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: And now what do you call the concrete class? *shudder* `ItemImpl` ?? This isn't Java! :)

Comment: +1 for having some balls. Even though I totally disagree with you. (A coworker of mine leaves out the `I` prefix as well, and I secretly hate him for it.)

Comment: @DanTao, time to beat your co-worker round the head with your coding standards doc? ;=)

Comment: I completely agree with your arguments. Really. But I can't vote for this answer, because the I for interfaces is standard in .NET. Yeah, it's the li'l brother of the Hungarian. But doing otherwise is bullshit. The world is not perfect.

Comment: +1.  Because it's convention doesn't make it right.  Nothing changes if you keep doing the same thing and there's no good reason for the 'I'.  Just say no to prefixes!

Comment: +1 Because people being unfair to you, while they just follow a convention blindly, whatever C# or ASP does doesn't make it right.

Answer (score 3):

According to .Net naming convention Interface name should be preceded by Capital Letter 'I' Followed by Name of interface in Camel case.

So I suggest you to to name interface Item as:

```
IItem
```

Not necessary to Mention 'Interface' at the end because The Letter 'I' at the Start itself says that it is Interface, not require to mention explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the MS guys is using [System.ComponentModel.IItemProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iitemproperties.aspx)